# Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. Prove or Disprove: If $o(g^m)=n$ then $o(g)=mn$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$.

Prove or Disprove: If $o(g^m)=n$ then $o(g)=mn$.

My try:
$(g^m)^n =e$
$g^{mn}=e \Rightarrow o(g)\le mn$
How can we continue from here?

Comment: Please try some examples.  Suppose $g=e$, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come on, now; you can use your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4375660/104041).

Consider $g=(12)=g^3$. Then $o(g^3)=2$ but $o(g)=2\neq 2\times 3=6$.